# Javascript turn normal function into constructor

Tags: javascript, object

Is there an (easy) way of compiling/turning this:

```
function b(){
  foo = 9;
  function bar(){alert(foo)};
}
```

into something like this:

```
var b = function(){
  this.foo = 9;
  this.bar = function(){alert(this.foo)};
}
```

Or something else so that i can use it like this:

```
a = new b();
a.bar();
```

Without changing the written code or syntax, purely by (pre)compiling the code?

Comment: is there a problem with the second snippet?

Comment: Why do you have the first syntax at all (given that it doesn't work)?

Comment: I would like to define the scope of a whole javascript file so that if the function bar is definend in that file, it is calleble via filename.bar (or something like that)

Comment: But why did you wrap that file in this `function b` then? You should simply use a module pattern for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately - not easily. The way your two examples work is entirely different (I might be writing what you already know, but to be sure, let's reiterate):

```
function b(){
  foo = 9;
  function bar(){alert(foo)};
}
```

This operates on a global scope - all the assignments are done to the `window` object.

```
var b = function(){
  this.foo = 9;
  this.bar = function(){alert(this.foo)};
}
```

This creates objects and operates with local scopes.

For the first example to work like the second one, you'd have to operate on clones of `window` object, which makes me shudder. It's doable - but you're better with refactoring the code you provided examples of.